# How to export more than 30K rows from Log Analytics Workspace on the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azureportal, azure-log-analytics-workspace

My team is working on various options to pipeline data out of a `Log Analytics Workspace`. But in the meantime I need to run some analyses on the data so am striving to export the data directly.   How can I export the whole table instead of just the first 30K rows of the query? (If it were like a few hundred K rows i'd do windowing/paging but it's a few million rows so that is too unwieldy.

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to export the data to ?

Comment: @Harshitha A local file

Comment: Export to Excel file ?

Comment: The default is csv which is just fine / excel compatible. That does bring up that setting the delimiter is awkward, but  I think i had managed to find a system setting (for pipe delimited)

Answer (score 1):

Log Analytics workspace has the limit of only 30000 rows. To achieve your requirement, you can try Azure Data explorer as a workaround.

Create an ADX cluster and go to the Query tab. Create a Log analytics workspace connection like below.

[image]

Follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data#add-a-log-analyticsapplication-insights-workspace-to-azure-data-explorer-client-tools) for step-by-step process of this.

ADX also, has 500000 rows limitation. To overcome it, use `set notruncation;` in query and now you can query your log analytics table and export the required amount of data like below sample.

[image]

Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/query-limits) to know more about this.